# ShowInTaskbar=true makes my form disappear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

App is compiled for .NET 2.0 (if its relevant).
Initially form is created with ShowInTaskbar=false, it does not appear in taskbar and everything is cool. However when certain action (dragging file on the form and starting file upload) does ShowInTaskbar=true (in order to show progress with changing window title/win7 taskbar functionality) then main form disappears. this.Show(), this.Visible=true - they dont help. Form is nowhere to be found until ShowInTaskbar=false is executed. Then it appears in same spot where it went missing... Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Changing ShowInTaskbar has big side-effects, Winforms must re-create the window.  One bug is that the form disappears from Application.OpenForms.  Never heard of it getting invisible though.  Look at the Output window for possible exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question has been asked over a year ago but it still pops up from time to time in google search results.

As stated when setting ShowInTaskbar windows recreates the entire form (or something like that ). So, if you have input fields or any controls like that they will be reset.

In my case, I used ShowInTaskbar = false when I want to minimize my application to the notification tray area, so that my app no longer appears in the taskbar when minimized. The problem comes when you restore the application to FormWindowState.Normal all the controls that you previously had are reset.

The work around is to remove all the controls "this.Controls.Remove(control1)" from the form before calling ShowInTaskbar = false and then re-add "this.Controls.Add(control1)" them once the form is restored.

That's my work around.
Hope it helps you and others.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        Button button = new Button { Text = "Toggle" };
        button.Click += delegate { form.ShowInTaskbar = !form.ShowInTaskbar; };
        form.Controls.Add(button);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Admittedly it flickers when you toggle it, but that shouldn't be too important. Do you have any events which might be fired as part of the change, which might be hiding your form?

Comment: tomorrow ill try to put together a testcase, see if i could replicate behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Is your application busy between the ShowInTaskBar=true and ...=false?

Your application may be asked to respond to messages and redraw its window, so if it is busy processing and does not return control to the message-processing loop, it won't respond (and therefore update the screen) until after you've finished doing everything.

If this is the case you may need to fire off your processing on a Windows.Forms.Timer or even use another thread (BackgroundWorker or ThreadPool) to allow your UI to continue being responsive while you are doing your processing.

Comment: it processes events just fine. when its made to show up in taskbar upload progress there is being displayed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with a panel disappearing when I would set the "ShowInTaskbar" to false.  Then when I would try to set it back to true, panel was still missing.  It was driving me nuts as all other controls were fine, except the panel.  It showed "enabled", "visible" all true, location and size were the same before and after "ShowInTaskbar" was set.  I came across this post and this is what worked for me.  Hope it helps others.

```
void ShowTaskbarIcon(bool e)
    {
        try
        {
            mf.Controls.Remove(mf.pnlMain);
            mf.ShowInTaskbar = e;
            mf.Controls.Add(mf.pnlMain);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ec.Get(ex.ToString(), 55, 1);
        }
    }
```

Basically I remove and add as already stated here in the answers.  I just want to thank everyone for helping me provide a solution.